# Using $searchEscaped to Show specific data

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

I'm using $searchEscaped to allow users to "view their profile" but this result is not working for me. Here's my code:

here's the link that users click to view their profile

```
 <li><a href="profile2.php?username=<?php echo $userRow['username'];?>">View Profile</a></li>
```

and then it sends them to the profile.php page. which is this below.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

$searchEscaped = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$res=mysql_query("SELECT username , image FROM users WHERE username='$searchEscaped'");
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);



$conn->close();
?>  

<?php echo $userRow['username']; ?>
<?php echo $userRow['image']; ?>
```

Any help would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you don't escape the string?

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php   
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "database";

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection


        if (!$conn) {
             die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $searchEscaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['username']);
        $res=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username , image FROM users WHERE username='$searchEscaped'");
        $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);



        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>

        <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?>
        <?php echo $userRow['image']; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`. There's no doubt that this is the cause of your issue.

I've transformed your code into `PDO` which protects you against SQL Injection Attacks.

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password);

$searchEscaped = $_GET['username'];

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, image FROM users WHERE username=:searchEscaped");
$stmt->bindParam(':searchEscaped', $searchEscaped);
$stmt->execute();
$userRow = $stmt->fetch(); 

echo $userRow['username']; 
echo $userRow['image'];
?>
```